# What can I say about the resulting variable?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable, having pdf $f(x)$ and let be $Y=f(X)$.
I have already proved these two following results:

1. If $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$ if and only if

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x, \qquad x \in \,[0, \sqrt{2}] \\
0, \qquad otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

2. If $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing, $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$ if and only if

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{a^{2}}{x}, \qquad x \in \,[ae^{-\frac{1}{2a^2}}, ae^{\frac{1}{2a^2}}] \\
0, \qquad otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

Now, I should investigate about the random variable that has pdf partially increasing and partially decreasing:

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x, \qquad x \in [0,1] \\
\frac{1}{x}, \qquad x \in \,[1, e^{\frac{1}{2}}] 
\end{cases}
$$

What can I say about the distribution of the random variable having aforementioned pdf? Do the last pdf have some simmetry ($\frac{1}{x}$ is the reciprocal of $x$)?

Comment: It is impossible for a PDF $f(x)$ to be strictly increasing. Recall that a PDF must be nonnegative and integrate to 1.

Answer (score 0):

$Y\in [0,1]$,

$$Y=\begin{cases} X, & X \in [0,1] \\ \frac1X, & X \in [1, e^\frac12]\end{cases}$$

If $y \in [0, e^{-\frac12}],$

\begin{align}
P(Y \le y) &= P(X \le y)\\
&= \int_0^y x \, dx
\end{align}

$$f_Y(y) = y$$
If $y \in [e^{-\frac12}, 1]$,

\begin{align}
P(Y\le y) &= \int_0^y f(x) \, dx + \int_{\frac1y}^{e^\frac12} f(x) \, dx\\
&=\int_0^yx \, dx + \int_{\frac1y}^{e^{\frac12}} \frac1x \, dx
\end{align}

$$f_Y(y) = y-y\left( -\frac1{y^2}\right)=y+\frac1y$$

In summary,

$$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} y, & y\in [0, e^{-0.5}]\\ y + \frac1y , & y \in [e^{-0.5},1] \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Answer (score -1):

Assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable and bijective on its support. Then by the classical transformation rule $Y$ has density $p$ with
\begin{equation}
p(x)=x|(f^{-1})'(x)|
\end{equation}
if $x\in\operatorname{im}(\operatorname{supp}(f))$ and $f'(f^{-1}(x))\ne 0$. Elsewhere it's zero. This can be generalised in various ways. For non-bijective functions, you can split up the function in bijective parts. Also the differantiability assumption can be relaxed, it becomes somewhat technical then however.

Comment: How can I use these informations in my specific case of interest?

Comment: You wanted to know something about the distribution of $Y=f(X)$, with $f$ being the density of $X$. That's precisely what I adressed.